# Open PDF manual after MSI installation

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Unable to create custom action in WXS file to open a downloaded PDF file.

I am creating an MSI file and dropping a small pdf manual to disk using this:

```
<!-- Step x: Add files to your installer package -->
        <DirectoryRef Id="Test">
            <Component Id="Dummy" Guid="AA0FBF6B-45F7-443D-8835-BDF4F3E57D47">
                <RemoveFile Id="BFaFvewqsa" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" Directory="Test"/>
                <File Id="Dummy" Source="doc.pdf" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
```

I would like to open the PDF after the installation is completed.
How do i do it ?

I am using the following but it does not work

```
        <Binary Id="ereEsWd" SourceFile="doc.pdf"/>

        <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#doc.pdf]"/>

        <CustomAction Id="ShowManual" 
        Return="ignore" 
        BinaryKey="ereEsWd"
        DllEntry="WixShellExec" 
        Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="ShowManual" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```